# Access an ASA via MGMT port

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, firewall

I'm working on an ASA 5520.

I have given the MGMT port an IP address, I can ping it ...

I have given it the name REMOTE `nameif REMOTE` and access level 100 ...

Then I allowed HTTP server `http server enable` ... and used the `http 0 0 REMOTE` command to allow access ...

But I get nothing when I try navigate to a webpage. .. any ideas?

Comment: Can you ssh?  Do you have a route?

Comment: No I can't SSH... I setup an account like you would on a router for SSH. I'm not too familiar with ASA's so I could be doing completely stupid here.

Comment: Please edit your question to include  your (sanitized) configuration.  Without it, we're just guessing.

Comment: Please accept your own answer, so that your questions does not keep popping up. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the above was OK....

It was a browser issue...

Navigating to the ip addressthat the MGMT Interface was assigned, in a web-browser, e.g. `192.168.1.90` .... I was getting a failed connection...

Reading up on it, I needed to go to `https://192.168.1.90/admin`

I then got the cert error and then the homepage...

I'm having an issue with Java, but that's another problem altogether.

Comment: Please accept your own answer, so that your questions does not keep popping up. :-)